# Why is there a hidden appWidget on home screen?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

After removing my last appWidget instance from home screen, `onDisabled`, `onEnabled` not working.

I register my widget as a broadcast receiver, there is no instance on home screen but broadcast receives and also I see my logs that written in my appWidget core class!

After uninstalling my application and installing it again, the problem solved and `onDisabled`, `onEnabled` worked correctly after adding(removing) first(last) instance.

I gathered appWidgetIds manually and holding it in a file to provide some better way to access all my widgets ids, but the hidden appWidget not removed from my collected widget ids and also exist in home screen!

**The Question:**

Is the problem a bug on Android Version 2.3.4(Testing Device)? and in this case what is the solution?

**Important part of codes:**

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    G.logger.out("Enabled");
    super.onEnabled(context);
}


@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    G.logger.out("Disabled");
    File file = new File(G.infoDir + "/" + getClass().getSimpleName() + ".dat");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    WidgetProperty property = G.widgetPropertyMap.get(getClass().getSimpleName());
    property.appWidgetIds = appWidgetIds;

    addWidgetIds(appWidgetIds, getClass().getSimpleName()); // add widget ids to a file ( duplicates will skip )
    updateAll(getClass(), context);
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    G.logger.out("Deleted");
    removeWidgetIds(appWidgetIds, getClass().getSimpleName()); // remove widget ids from file
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very bad design on AppWidgets in android.

To reproduce the bug:

- Select Widget ( to drop on home screen )
- Select Back ( hardware key ) to cancel drop widget
- Now you have hidden widget.

I was included `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);` to prevent this issue, but will not handle by android framework!!!

So I used this code as an stupid solution:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if ( !submitted) {
        AppWidgetHost host = new AppWidgetHost(this, 1);
        host.deleteAppWidgetId(mAppWidgetId);
    }
}
```